# create a copy of table with PROC COPY with flexible names and libs

Tags: sas, copy

I read that a `PROC COPY` is faster than a `DATA` step .

I understand how the following works :

```
proc copy in=lib1 out=lib2;
    select have;
run;
```

However I'd like some flexibility on the name of the output, mainly because I want to copy a table in the same library as the source.

Basically I want (if possible at all) the more efficient version of :

```
DATA lib1.have;
set lib2.want;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if PROC COPY is faster than a data step it is probably because it knows that it does not need to manipulate the data before writing it back out.

Why not use PROC APPEND for what you want?  Use the BASE= option to set the target table and the DATA= option to set the source table.

```
proc append data=lib1.have base=lib2.want ;
run;
```

If you want to make sure there is not already a table `lib2.want` then add a `proc delete` step before it.

```
proc delete data=lib2.want; 
run;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post.  The log will say that the base data does not exist, so the table is being copied.  I always do this inside a `proc datasets`, with a prior `delete` statement, just  in case the append is run more than once